# Does GeForce support GPU-accelerated video processing with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia

[On this page](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix), it says "GeForce" is supported

> HW accelerated encode and decode are supported on NVIDIA **`GeForce`**, Quadro, Tesla, and GRID products with Fermi, Kepler, Maxwell and Pascal generation GPUs.

But I cannot find `GeForce` in the listed matrix on the same page. So does `GeForce` support or not?

Answer (score 2):

If the GPU is supported, then yes. nVidia doesn't want to market Geforce as compute cards, that's the likely reason for their omission from that matrix.

See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17419/1871 for details, especially

> only 2 video transcoding threads can be run simultaneously
>   on a consumer level NVIDIA card, but this regulated on driver level.
>   And with a strong desire this limitation may be removed then a maximum
>   transcoding threads will be depend of a video memory size and Video
>   Engine utilization, but for one transcoding thread for different video
>   cards is necessary different video memory size. For example, one
>   ffmpeg thread cost is 100 MB video on QUADRO K 4200(4GB) and 170 MB on
>   GTX 980 TI(6GB).